# New line break in survey of sharepoint 2007

Tags: survey-list

In sharepoint 2007,i am creting a survey.In description of that survey,i want to enter each sentence in a new line..so it's like
1)Excellant
2)Really good
3)Good

So how can i put line break at the end of each statemnt in overview.aspx..

Answer (score 1):

1) add some special symbol to your description
2) add a content editor webpart to your survey overview page and add there a javascript that will correct your description using you special symbol